# Catch the moment I get a NaN in my calculations

Tags: python, exception, crash, nan, infinity

I am running loops with linear regression and got calculations going where I often end up with infinities. When I check the variable output, I note that things crash when I start getting "NaNs". I've tried a lot of different ways of dealing with infinities but my program still ends up crashing. I've done things like replace NaNs with very large or very small values, but now I'm thinking this is all no use. I shouldn't be treating all NaNs equally - apparently some NaNs come about while playing with positive infinities, and some with negative infinities.

I really need to know at WHICH point exactly does my code suddenly produce a NaN, and whether it was a negative infinity that produced it, or a positive one. How can I do this, before the program crashes?

### Edit

I know how to *check* for NaN. I can simply use `numpy.isnan`, and I have used it. But I want to know *when* it happens. Isn't there an exception or something that can be called or throw a warning when it happens?

Comment: can share your code . so that it can be found?

Comment: _"I've done things like replace NaNs with very large or very small values, but now I'm thinking this is all no use"_ This is mainly meaningless. _NaN_ is for example _infinity/infinity_ . Replacing that blindly by 'very low' or 'very large value' is plain wrong.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux yes exactly, that's what I've realized, which is s why I want to know at what point the NaN is and what's causing it.

Comment: No it's not a duplicate, I know how to "check for it", all I do is use isnan, but I want to check *when* it happens, so I can see why.

Comment: What, specifically, are you doing?  How you should handle exceptional cases usually depends heavily on the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Just trying to debug my code and figure out where it is that these dangerous NaNs first appear, which are the reason my code keeps crashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to *trap* a numeric exception using numpy, your best bet is probably to use [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

For example, to raise an exception on invalid operation (leading to *NaN*):

```
import numpy as np

np.seterr(invalid='raise')
np.float64(0)/0.
```

Producing that display on the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h.py", line 4, in <module>
    np.float64(0)/0.
FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Comment: I see. So you're saying I add the np.seterr line above the one that I suspect might be causing the NaN?

Comment: FYI: The corresponding context manager is `np.errstate` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I had more in mind to change globally the "exception" handling as the OP did not known precisely where the problem is located. But for narrower scope, `np.errstate` is clearly the way to go.